# How to fetch record from .imp file in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a payload which is coming from a .imp file, the records inside the payload
[ORDRUPDT|U|O-40541|C|
ORDRUPDT|U|O-40536|C|
ORDRUPDT|U|O-40537|C|
ORDRUPDT|U|O-40538|C|
ORDRUPDT|U|O-40539|C|
ORDRUPDT|U|O-40540|C|]
I need to fetch value of column 1, 4 and 3, in mule 3 we can fetch using $[0], $[2] etc. but in mule 4 $[0] syntax doesn't support.
can you please help me to fetch the record.

Comment: Hi @Neelpawan Kalita. Does the original input contains the square brackets? Also, what kind of line separator is it using?

Comment: Hi @Neelpawan Kalita. Let's assume no one here knows what is an .imp file. Please describe the input format as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
---
payload
    replace "[" with("")
    replace "]" with("")
    replace(" ") with ("")
    splitBy("|")
    divideBy 4
    map() -> $[0] ++ "|" ++ $[3] ++ "|" ++ $[2]
```

Result:

```
[
  "ORDRUPDT|C|O-40541",
  "ORDRUPDT|C|O-40536",
  "ORDRUPDT|C|O-40537",
  "ORDRUPDT|C|O-40538",
  "ORDRUPDT|C|O-40539",
  "ORDRUPDT|C|O-40540"
]
```